# Fan speed and heating problem on macbook pro 9,2 running Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, macbook, overheating, fan

I used to run Ubuntu 12.04 with Vmware on my macbook pro 13 inch (9,2). Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 13.04 with dual boot with rEFit. I started facing over heating problem while running Ubuntu even on very low loads (for example fetching mails through thunderbird). I installed macfanctld which solved the over heating problem but now the fans are making a lot of noise. They keep on running all the time on high speed. 
Can anyone tell me how to fix it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I literally just went through this process and wished that I had documented it better to help others.  I installed http://task3.cc/projects/mbpfan/ which seems to have helped a lot with the fan issues.  I also changed some settings for power management which might have helped fan control indirectly (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks). Let me know if this helps at all, if not I can try and retrace my steps in a more detailed manner.

Comment: Could you specify what tweaks you performed from the Wiki?

Comment: I performed all of the "enable" steps (you'll have to add them all to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line).  I did not toy with  "Enable Aggressive Link Power Management" as the authors highlighted out the potential for data loss.  Does this help?  I also disabled bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks for the details. By the way, there's a PPA for mbpfan at https://launchpad.net/~mactel-support/+archive/ppa.

Comment: +1 to this answer, because I am biased towards it :-)
@papukaija that ppa is for obtaining macfanctld (among other things). mbpfan is not on a ppa (as I am aware of). The only way to use it is to compile it from source.